# Android NDK C++ openGL ES 2 context gives bad display

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, android-ndk

I am trying to implement a openGL ES 2.0 game using NDK in C++ . My test device was ASUS Zenphone 5
I am pretty sure it supports openGL ES 2.0 as it can run games based on openGL ES 2 from play store very smoothly and also the helloGl2 sample in androind NDK.

When I called `glCreateShader` log cat gave an error "called unimplemented api" by googling a bit I found out it was because the app was using openGL ES 1 context by default.

So I modified the EGL context creation code from:

```
context = eglCreateContext(display, config, NULL, NULL);
```

to

```
EGLint contextAttrs[] = {
        EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION,2,EGL_NONE
};

context = eglCreateContext(display, config, NULL, contextAttrs);
```

Now this gave a different error

```
 E/libEGL(12670): validate_display:257 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
```

However when I tested it on a galaxy s3 (GT-I9100) there was no BAD DISPLAY ERROR , but the app crashed on calling glCreateShader with fatal signal SIGSEV

What is going on here?

Comment: How are you setting the value of `display`? You may also want to show the `config` selection code. Even though the error does indeed suggest that the problem is with the display.

Comment: Yes , sorry I just realized I should have posted the display code too as the final problem turns out to be in the eglchooseconfig attributes (EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT), Anyway thanks for the input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are creating an ES 2 context, you also need to include `EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT` in the attributes for the EGL config, it's not enough to add `EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2` to the context attributes.

Also, make sure you are linking to libGLESv2.so (`-lGLESv2` in `LOCAL_LDLIBS`), and make sure you aren't linking in libGLESv1_CM.so by accident. (Using them both in the same process requires a bit of extra trickery.)

Comment: Oye awesome man! that did the trick! I had to add EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT and bam all errors gone

Comment: What examples would that be, that link against GLESv2 but only use GLES 1 APIs (and use EGL to set up a GLES 1 context, I presume)? When I grepped for GLESv2 in the NDK samples directory, I didn't find any examples that weren't labelled correctly.

Comment: If you mean the `native-activity` sample in the NDK, it only links to GLESv1_CM.